# Adding Match operators dynamically in a Group Aggregate on MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using `MongoDB C# driver 2.4.4` in my web application. I need to group documents in a collection filtering them dynamically.

```
 var query = collection.Aggregate()
                .Match(y => y.IdLower.Contains(id))
                .Match(y => y.NameLower.Contains(name))
                .Group(
                key => key.Id,
                g => new 
                {
                    Id = g.Key
                }).ToList();
```

I need to add or remove `Match` operators based to user input but I cannot figure how.

I tried something like this:

```
 var query = collection.Aggregate();

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
         query = query.Match(y => y.IdLower.Contains(id));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        query = query.Match(y => y.NameLower.Contains(name));

    query =  query.Group(
        key => key.Id,
        g => new 
        {
            Id = g.Key
        }).ToList();
```

but I get syntax error `Cannot imlicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Id>> to '...`

How to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type of `query` is `IAggregateFluent<T1>` (where `T1` is your document type), but the return type of the `.Group()` method is `IAggregateFluent<T2>` (where `T2` is an anonymous type). The compiler does not know how to implicitly convert these types, hence the error.

It depends on what you're trying to do here, but one possible way to fix this would be to return instances of `T1` (your document type) from the group expression:

```
query = query.Group(
    key => key.Id,
    g => new T1 // replace "T1" with the actual name of your class
    {
        Id = g.Key
    }).ToList();
```

Another option would be to assign the results of the `group` function to a new variable:

```
var grouped = query.Group(
    key => key.Id,
    g => new 
    {
        Id = g.Key
    }).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.